# Rails 3 - Nested Form and has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, has-many-through

---

Hi people, long time not been here. But I'm back because I need your help again please. I have a rails 3.0.9 app, and I'm working with nested forms and has_many through association. When i create an instance, it works great. The problems come when I try to edit. Here is an example for a better explanation. (table names and attributes are just for explaining)

Table Client

- id
- company_name
- address

Table Worker

- id
- first_name
- last name

Table Contact

- id
- client_id
- worker_id

my models looks like these

```
class Worker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :clients, :through => :contacts, :foreign_key => 'client_id'
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts, :foreign_key => "client_id",:dependent => :destroy
  has_many :workers, :through => :contacts, :foreign_key => 'worker_id'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workers, :allow_destroy => false
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :worker, :foreign_key => "worker_id"
  belongs_to :client, :foreign_key => "client_id"
end
```

Then in my form for create a client, I can create many workers, and rails make the association and creates the instances for the contacts table (by using nested forms).

The thing is, if I want to edit a client by removing a contact, the contact is not removed. As you can see I put this line in the clients model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :workers, :allow_destroy => false
```

I set the allow_destroy to false, because I don't want to delete the worker itself, I just want to remove the contact tuple.

Does anybody know how can I solve this?? Hope you can help me... Thanks